# Metodologias ágeis - um só programador

Tags: modelagem, metodologia, scrum

Tenho ouvido falar muito sobre metodologias ágeis e gostei bastante da ideia. Claro que pelo que vi, o cliente precisa cooperar, mas me parece que para projetos próprios (ou seja, cuja ideia seja minha e não de um cliente) essas metodologias podem ajudar bastante.

Minha dúvida, na realidade, é se essas ideias todas se aplicam a programadores que trabalham sozinhos. A ideia de agilidade, na primeira vez que a vi, parecia ser basicamente a ideia de quebrar o processo de desenvolvimento de um software em várias iterações, cada uma composta por análise, design e programação.

Pesquisando mais, porém, tudo que achei se relaciona com equipes. Achei várias formas de se usar metodologias ágeis, como Scrum, etc. Mas tudo que eu lia sobre o assunto falava sobre equipes, dividir tarefas, etc.

Minha pergunta é: existe uma forma de se utilizar metodologias ágeis trabalhando sozinho? Se sim, onde posso ver mais sobre isso?

Comment: Conheço umas figuras que só usam **[XGH](http://bit.ly/1ssehq2)**. Mais ágil que isso, impossível.    /s

Comment: Hahaha, já trabalhei com pessoas que nem sabem o que é XGH mas são exatamente assim.

Comment: @Bacco - Cara, você não faz ideia do quanto ri desse link.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

O Solo Scrum é interessante e, conforme a [resposta do @Caputo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14274/112052), foi usado por algumas pessoas com sucesso.

Mas tenha em mente que não será um Scrum "puro", já que o foco original é no **Time** e vários benefícios da metodologia serão perdidos, como no *daily meeting*, onde cada um pode expor os impedimentos e obter orientação dos demais.

Além disso, estimar sozinho no modelo ágil é um problema. Você não vai ter como fazer o *Planning Poker* ou algum outro método em que haja confronto entre a visão de vários desenvolvedores.

Por outro lado, faça bom uso dos *time boxes* para obter uma entrega contínua de um executável, evitar a procrastinação e não se perder no tempo.

Já no que se refere a controlar as atividades, em minha opinião, o método mais eficiente num contexto ágil é um quadro Kanban:

[image: Kanban]

Então você pode definir suas *tasks* ou mesmo *User stories* (histórias de usuário) e ter uma boa ideia visual do andamento dos seus projetos pessoais.

Answer (score 29):

A resposta curta para a pergunta é **Sim!** Eu tenho o hábito de pegar alguns projetos freela e o que eu faço é utilizar o ScrumBoard para controlar o que devo fazer e o BurnDown para acompanhar a minha produtividade com o esperado.

Neste **[link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160322173758/http://www.pbell.com/index.cfm/2007/6/17/Solo-Scrums)** ele fala de um Scrum adaptado e chama de **SoloScrum**.

Este **[outro link](http://blog.myscrumhalf.com/2012/01/possui-metas-para-2012-o-scrum-pode-ajudar/)** traz, em português, uma forma de usar scrum para metas em geral ( o que se encaixa no que você deseja)

### Edição

Quando estou trabalhando sozinho sigo os seguintes passos:

#### Definição do Product BackLog

Anoto nos Post-its e colo na primeira divisão do meu quadro em frente o PC, avalio e dou um peso de 1 a 5 para cada

#### Definição do Sprint BackLog

Pego os Post-its que pretendo fazer na semana e coloco na segunda parte, sabendo qual é minha média de produtividade semanal

#### Diariamente

Pego o PostIt do que quero fazer e movo para **Em implementação**. Quando termino movo para **Em Teste** que nem sempre faço na sequência

Passado o teste movo para **Feito**

no fim do dia atualizo o meu BurnDown do projeto / sprint e vejo se está dentro do planejado ou se vou ter q fazer um esforço maior nos fins de semana ou ganhar umas noites de folga.

Answer (score 6):

Em um projeto solo, as maiores contribuições que você pode obter do Ágil são o décimo e o sétimo princípio do [Manifesto](http://agilemanifesto.org/) (nesta mesma ordem):

> 10º) Simplicidade, a arte de maximizar a quantidade de trabalho não
> feito, é essencial.
>
> 7º) Software funcionando é a medida primária de progresso.

**Trabalhando sozinho pode ser mais fácil envolver-se em desperdício** (as *"boas idéias"* que temos durante o percurso ou a preferência por trabalhar em um requisito por ser mais desafiador e não por ser prioritário) do que trabalhando em um time, onde a pressão vem de todos os lados.

Fora isso, os valores e a maioria dos princípios do Manifesto Ágil tratam de projetos de software que envolvem cliente e equipe, portanto as metodologias para projetos Ágeis também são voltadas para projetos envolvendo cliente e equipe. De modo que você não vai beneficiar-se de uma metodologia Ágil tipo Extreme Programming ou Scrum, mas você vai se beneficiar de algumas práticas destas metodologias: lista de requisitos priorizada (**backlog**), acompanhamento do progresso (**software funcionando**), **Simple Design**, **TDD**...

Quanto a **estimativas, trabalhando sozinho você não precisa delas**. Não perca tempo. Se ninguém pediu estimativas, fazer estimativas é um **desperdício**; principalmente se forem de curto prazo (*"quantos requisitos eu terminarei esta semana"*). Dê manutenção apenas nas suas estimativas de médio e longo prazo: *"o que é a versão mínima viável do meu produto e quando eu a termino"*.

Minha recomendação geral é aprender a cultura Ágil e as práticas e técnicas que a suportam, assim fica fácil usufruir dela em vários cenários, mesmo trabalhando sozinho.

Comment: Acabei encontrando o assunto e me interessei. Após ler todas as metodologias indicadas, essa sem dúvida foi a mais completa. Pois tem uma visão pra frente, não se prende a rotinas que atrasaria o desenvolvimento e também não chega nem perto de ser um XGH heheh. Claro que cada empresa pode ter uma maneira de trabalhar, depende da visão do líder (ou do programador no caso de trabalhar sozinho), o que importa é a confiança e a facilidade em lidar com a metodologia escolhida, mesmo sendo a XGH.

Answer (score 3):

Acho que o Lean atualmente é a metodologia mais eficaz e se pode aplicar "sozinho", ou seja, se você seja o único envolvido diretamente com o cliente...

Nesses casos pode ser aplicado com "êxito", pois estou utilizando essa metodologia para atender uma empresa que apóz quase um ano, começa demostrar satisfação pelo serviço.

Mais geralmente você nunca está sozinho e isso só funciona quando todos envolvidos entendam o processo, e que você tenha recursos para poder lidar com a necessidade do cliente de uma forma que não te comprometa.

O Lean bem aplicado é sucesso absoluto nos negócios, mais a dificuldade de aplicação é muito grande, e é muito difícil convencer um cliente a seguir tal metodologia, tendo em vista que os negócios são os mais transparentes possíveis. É isso mesmo! Tem cliente que prefere o básico e não está aberto a outros processos. Se quiser saber mais sobre Lean veja aqui http://www.lean.org.br/

Answer (score 1):

Sim cara, tranquilamente.

Crie tarefas, descreva-as, estime-as, priorize-as e por fim trabalhe com pequenas iterações, assim você pode ter noção da evolução do seu trabalho.

Se quiser saber mais a respeito, dê uma olhada no [Scrum Guide](https://www.scrum.org/Portals/0/Documents/Scrum%20Guides/2013/Scrum-Guide-Portuguese-BR.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Segundo o guia Scrum da Scrum.org:

O melhor tamanho é aquele pequeno suficiente para permanecer ágil e grande o suficiente para completar um trabalho significativo dentro de uma sprint.

Equipes com menos que três desenvolvedores tem a interação reduzida e tem ganhos de produtividade menores. Equipes de desenvolvimento menores podem encontrar barreiras técnicas durante uma sprint, tornando-as incapazes de realizar uma entrega de tamanho aceitável.

Ter mais de nove membros requer muita coordenação. Equipes grandes geram muita complexidade para gerenciar um processo empírico.

O fato é, ter um programador apenas não é recomendado pela Scrum.org

Fonte: http://www.scrumguides.org/docs/scrumguide/v2016/2016-Scrum-Guide-US.pdf#zoom=100

Answer (score 0):

Caro Leonardo, o SCRUM é será mais benéfico se utilizado por equipes de 3 a 9 participantes.

Este detalhe é importante porque em outras configurações, menores ou maiores, há perdas no tocante à capacidade de colaboração e comunicação.

No caso de um único desenvolvedor não faz sentido a adoção do SCRUM por ser uma prática direcionada para equipes, imagine uma única pessoa acumulando os papéis de Scrum master, Product owner e Development Team.

Agora, nada o impede de adotar algumas boas práticas que são comuns SCRUM, por exemplo, a organização dos requisitos em forma de user-stories, a priorização do backlog conforme a importância dos requisitos, a definição de um ritmo de entrega destes requisitos (a cada 1, 2, 3 semanas...).

Ao final, você acabará por criar uma metodologia de trabalho própria inspirada no SCRUM. Devem existir algumas idéias similares na Internet. Sugiro que pesquise algo nesta linha, mas sem se perder em divagações puramente teóricas.